# Mockito/Spy not working, executing the original function

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, spy

I am having a class :

GP_CategoryService.java
Function -->

```
public JSONObject deleteCategory(GP_CategorySubcategoryBean bean) {
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        DirectoryCategoryMaster oCategory = getCategoryMaster(bean);

        if (oCategory.getDirCategoryId() != null) {
            boolean isDeleted = delete(oCategory);
            data.put(ConstantUtil.STATUS, ConstantUtil.SUCCESS);
            data.put(ConstantUtil.DATA, "Category deleted successfully");
        } 
    }
```

I have 2 inner function calls :

1. getCategoryMaster(bean)
2. delete(oCategory)

These are basically DAO calls, updating the Database directly.
Now I want to mock these 2 fucntions alone such that whenever  my test function is running, it should return true.

I have written my test function as below :

```
@Test
    public void deleteCategoryTestDAOV() {
        JSONObject expected = new JSONObject();
        expected.put(ConstantUtil.STATUS, ConstantUtil.SUCCESS);
        expected.put(ConstantUtil.DATA, "Category deleted successfully");
        
        bean.setCategoryId(1);
        bean.setCategoryName("Test");
        DirectoryCategoryMaster master=new DirectoryCategoryMaster();
        master.setDirCategoryId(1);
        GP_CategoryService mock = spy(new GP_CategoryService());
        when(mock.delete(master)).thenReturn(true);
        when(mock.getCategoryMaster(bean)).thenReturn(master);
        JSONObject actual=new JSONObject();
        actual=mock.deleteCategory(bean);
        assertEquals(expected.toJSONString(), actual.toJSONString());   
    }
```

But when I am running the test class, its executing the actual fucntion, mock is not working. Can anhyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't mock the methods of the class being tested - mock the dependencies those methods use.  In this case, there is probably a `repository` (or similar) that those methods delegate to - so mock the `repository`.  If there is no `repository`, then create it!  Fix the code so it's easy to test (rather than fight how to test).

Comment: You need to use "@Mock" and "@InjectMocks".

Comment: @sonny I have used both, then also same issue. Please check the question again I have added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mockito works by creating a [CGLIB](https://github.com/cglib/cglib) proxy of the class under mock. For example, if you `mock(MyClass.class)`, you will get a dynamic proxy of class `MyClass$$EnhancedByMockito$$.class`, which extends `MyClass.class`. Since the proxy is a subclass of `MyClass`, the resulting class allows the user to override specific functionality ("mock" it). Most of the method interception is hidden behind the scenes for you by easy-to-use statements like `when`.

Unfortunately, due to limitations in Java, it is not possible to proxy internal method calls with native reflection. This is because, if you're directly calling instance method `MyClass:b` from instance method `MyClass::a`, there is no gap to insert a proxy class which extends `MyClass` to execute `MyClass::b` indirectly.

Technically, it's possible to do this with some really advanced bytecode manipulation (with something like ByteBuddy).

Example that does not work:

```java
class MyClass {
    public String doSomething() {
        return doSomethingElse();
    }
    
    public String doSomethingElse() {
        return "foo";
    }
}

// ...

class MyTest {

    private MyClass myClass;

    // ...
    @Test
    void myTest() {
        when(myClass.doSomethingElse()).thenReturn("Bar");
        assertEquals("bar", myClass.doSomething()); // FAILS
    }
}
```

Example that does work, using an intermediate class with overrideable methods:

```java
class MyClass {

    private MyClassBackend myClassBackend;

    public MyClass(MyClassBackend myClassBackend) {
        this.myClassBackend = myClassBackend;
    }

    public String doSomething() {
        return myClassBackend.doSomethingElse();
    }
}

class MyClassBackend {
    public String doSomethingElse() {
        return "foo";
    }
}

// ...

class MyTest {

    private MyClass myClass;

    @Mock
    private MyClassBackend myClassBackend;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        this.myClass = new MyClass(myClassBackend);
    }

    // ...
    @Test
    void myTest() {
        when(myClassBackend.doSomethingElse()).thenReturn("bar");
        assertEquals("bar", myClass.doSomething()); // PASSES
    }
}
```

Comment: If I put the functions which I want to mock in a new class then I should create object of the new class ? then how to hit from the actual service? Can you show me a similar working example ?

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect a working set-up