# Mockito/Spy not working, executing the original function with class dao

Tags: java, unit-testing, aws-lambda, mockito

i am new to unit testing with mockito i have tried several ways but it doesn't work i can't simulate the response of the method i always run the real method,

I create the objects in the methods as I am not using spring boot but another serverless framework because I could not configure the api for better dependency injection management.

`this is my unit test`

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class RequestBalancePersonServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private RequestBalancePersonService service;
    private DTORequestBalance dtoRequestBalance;
    private DTOIdAndNamesByNumberCellphone dtoIdAndNamesByNumberCellphone;
    private RequestBalancePersonEntity requestBalancePersonEntity;
    @Mock
    private CustomerWalledDao customerWalledDao;

    @Spy
    private RequestBalancePersonDao requestBalancePersonDao;
    @Spy
    private ReceivesBalancePersonService receivesBalancePersonService;


    private Intermedia intermedia;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        intermedia = new Intermedia(service);

        customerWalledDao = Mockito.spy(CustomerWalledDao.class);
        dtoRequestBalance = new DTORequestBalance();
        dtoRequestBalance.setClient_account_Requesting_Balance("+573138356431");
        dtoRequestBalance.setBalance(1000);
        dtoRequestBalance.setCustomer_account_whom_balance_requested("+573134688960");
        dtoRequestBalance.setTransaction_date(null);

        dtoIdAndNamesByNumberCellphone = new DTOIdAndNamesByNumberCellphone();
        dtoIdAndNamesByNumberCellphone.setCustomerId(21654654l);
        dtoIdAndNamesByNumberCellphone.setFirstName("Alexis");
        dtoIdAndNamesByNumberCellphone.setFirstSurname("Suarez");

        requestBalancePersonEntity = new RequestBalancePersonEntity();
        requestBalancePersonEntity.setRequestid(16624165l);
        requestBalancePersonEntity.setStatusId(3);
        requestBalancePersonEntity.setRequestchecked(false);
        requestBalancePersonEntity.setCustomerId(21654654l);
       // doReturn(dtoIdAndNamesByNumberCellphone).when(customerWalledDao).getIdAndNamesByNumberCellphone("+573138356431");
        //doReturn(1).when(requestBalancePersonDao).registerRequestBalance(requestBalancePersonEntity);
        //doReturn(1).when(receivesBalancePersonService).buildReceivesBalancePerson(requestBalancePersonEntity,dtoRequestBalance);
        // doReturn(dtoIdAndNamesByNumberCellphone).when(customerWalledDao).getIdAndNamesByNumberCellphone("+573138356431");
        //doReturn(1).when(requestBalancePersonDao).registerRequestBalance(requestBalancePersonEntity);
    }
    

    @Test
    void buildRequestBalance2() throws Exception{
            doReturn(dtoIdAndNamesByNumberCellphone).when(customerWalledDao).getIdAndNamesByNumberCellphone(nullable(String.class));
            doReturn(1).when(requestBalancePersonDao).registerRequestBalance(nullable(RequestBalancePersonEntity.class));
            doReturn(1).when(receivesBalancePersonService).buildReceivesBalancePerson(nullable(RequestBalancePersonEntity.class),nullable(DTORequestBalance.class));
            int result = service.buildRequestBalance(dtoRequestBalance);
            assertEquals(1, result);
    }

    @Test
    void buildRequestBalance3() throws Exception{
        doReturn(dtoIdAndNamesByNumberCellphone).when(customerWalledDao).getIdAndNamesByNumberCellphone("+573138356431");
        doReturn(1).when(requestBalancePersonDao).registerRequestBalance(requestBalancePersonEntity);
        doReturn(1).when(receivesBalancePersonService).buildReceivesBalancePerson(requestBalancePersonEntity,dtoRequestBalance);
        int result = service.buildRequestBalance(dtoRequestBalance);
        assertEquals(1, result);
    }
}
```

`this is my service`

```
public class RequestBalancePersonService {

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());


    public int buildRequestBalance(DTORequestBalance requestBalance){
        CustomerWalledDao customerWalledDao = new CustomerWalledDao();
        RequestBalancePersonDao requestBalancePersonDao = new RequestBalancePersonDao();
        int registrationCompleted = 0;
        RequestBalancePersonEntity requestBalancePerson = new RequestBalancePersonEntity();
        ReceivesBalancePersonService receivesBalancePersonService = new ReceivesBalancePersonService();
        try{

            DTOIdAndNamesByNumberCellphone resultDataCustomer = customerWalledDao.getIdAndNamesByNumberCellphone(requestBalance.getClient_account_Requesting_Balance());
            java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
            Long requestId = UniqueIDUtils.generateUniqueId(date);
            Timestamp transactionDate = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
            TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Bogota"));

            requestBalancePerson.setRequestid(requestId);
            requestBalancePerson.setStatusId(3);
            requestBalancePerson.setRequestchecked(false);
            requestBalancePerson.setCustomerId(resultDataCustomer.getCustomerId());

            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
            message.append(resultDataCustomer.getFirstName())
                    .append(" ").append(resultDataCustomer.getFirstSurname()).append(" ");
            message.append(System.getenv("requestMessages")).append(" ").append(requestBalance.getBalance());
            requestBalancePerson.setRequestmessages(message.toString());

            requestBalancePerson.setBalance(requestBalance.getBalance());
            requestBalancePerson.setRequestdate(transactionDate);
            int resultRegisterRequestBalance = requestBalancePersonDao.registerRequestBalance(requestBalancePerson);
            int receivesRegisterBalancePerson = receivesBalancePersonService.buildReceivesBalancePerson(requestBalancePerson,requestBalance);
            if (resultRegisterRequestBalance == 1 && receivesRegisterBalancePerson == 1){
                return registrationCompleted = 1;
            }
            if (resultRegisterRequestBalance == 1 && receivesRegisterBalancePerson == 0){
                logger.error("Error receivesBalancePerson");
            }

            if (resultRegisterRequestBalance == 0 && receivesRegisterBalancePerson == 1){
                logger.error("Error RequestBalancePerson");
            }

            if (resultRegisterRequestBalance == 0 && receivesRegisterBalancePerson == 0){
                logger.error("Error RequestBalancePerson");
                logger.error("Error receivesBalancePerson");
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error al construir request balance: "+e.getMessage());
        }
        return registrationCompleted;
    }
```

I was reading this publication and if this is true I would not be able to test my service as the sonarqube would not show the coverage.
[Mockito/Spy not working, executing the original function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65958351/mockito-spy-not-working-executing-the-original-function)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are my mocked methods not called when executing a unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027324/why-are-my-mocked-methods-not-called-when-executing-a-unit-test), specfically the section (Mis-)using @InjectMocks – you have your fields annotated already, if you reassigin them in your setup method, the original reference is lost